# How to return a false or true inside the useEffect and pass it to another useEffect method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to retrieve the value of the latest useEffect, which is true or false and pass it into the curly bracket of the first useEffect, so it will stop decrementing the countdown when it goes level up or down.

```js
    const curLevel = 2;
    const newTimer = curLevel * 15;
    const timeRef = useRef(null);
    const level = useRef(null);
    const [ seconds, setSeconds ] = useState(newTimer);

    // countdown

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1), 1000);
        timeRef.current = timer;
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(seconds === 0 || {pass returned value here} ) clearInterval(timeRef.current);
    }, [seconds]);

    // level comparison
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const storedLevel = curLevel;
      
        level.current = storedLevel;
        return () => storedLevel
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(level.current, curLevel) // outputs (2,3)
        if(level.current !== curLevel) {}
        // I want to get the value (which is true or false and pass it into the curly bracket of the first useEffect, so it will stop decrementing the countdown when it goes  level up or down.
    },[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that boolean property to the state and then track it in your first `useEffect`:

```
const [isCurrentlevel, setIsCurrentLevel] = useState(false);

//...
 useEffect(() => {
    if (isCurrentLevel) {
        const timer = setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1), 1000);
        timeRef.current = timer;
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, [isCurrentlevel]);

 useEffect(() => {
        console.log(level.current, curLevel) // outputs (2,3)
        setIsCurrentLevel(level.current !== curLevel);       
    },[level.current, curLevel]);
```